# 64-bit windows context menu inside 32-bit application (how to traverse owner-drawn menu?)

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I want to embed windows 64-bit context menu inside 32-bit application (something like X64 submenu in TotalCommander). To do this I need to simulate 64-bit menu contents at 32-bit side. My idea is to traverse 64-bit menu inside 64-bit helper process, and regenerate such content at 32-bit side (I also tried show such menu directly from 64-bit helper, but windows is surprised to have two context menus, each from different process, and doesn't paint second menu correctly). Tell me if you have other ideas.

I have one problem: some owner-drawn menus show more items than GetMenuItemCount() returns (usually GetMenuItemCount() returns 1 in such case).

Interesting is, that I can use GetMenuItemInfo() for owner-drawn menu item using item ID (wich is returned from TrackPopupMenuEx()), so such menu can generate proper info for every particular item. But unfortunatelly I cannot use IDs to iterate menu items (item IDs are unordered).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure how TotalCommand does it. But I found this:

- Start TOTALCMD.EXE (32-bit process)
- See that it is running in TaskManager (Keep it running on right/left side, and monitor processes/process-count.
- Now Launch the menu, the processes are still same.
- Hover over **X64** menu, and you see it takes time. This time when you see in TaskManager, another process named **TCMDX64.EXE** just started, and this is a 64-bit process.
- My understanding says that this spawned process gets the menu and sends back to the TotalCommander 32-bit application.

Comment: With all respect, did you read my question? I wrote that I already have 64-bit helper process. The problem I have is how to traverse some owner-drawn menus.

Comment: From which process you are enumerating the context menu? You can pass the menu informatoin from 64-bit helper process to 32-bit process. Or may be you need to add some more information here.

Comment: I enumerate menu using 64-bit process (I wrote this). And I want to pass it into 32-bit process, but it's not problem. Problem is, that I cannot enumerate some owner-drawn menus because GetMenuItemCount() returns untrue value.

Comment: I am not owner drawn menu expert, but it is possible that there is actually only one menu item and being displyed in parts. May be mouse-move is handled within menu itself and menu is highlighted using mouse position.

Comment: Well, as you probably know every menu item returns ID which can bu used to invoke proper command. Mentioned owner-drawn menus return ID as well, and using such ID I can call GetMenuItemInfo() to get SEPARATE item info, for every menu item. Situation looks this way: GetMenuItemCount() returns 1, menu returns few IDs, and I can use GetMenuItemInfo() for every returned ID. Problem is that I don't know IDs until menu is called, and I don't have proper items count.

Comment: Solution: some menus have to get WM_INITMENUPOPUP before GetMenuItemCount() and others.